# How to handle Jenkin's "Abort build" gracefully?

Tags: python, jenkins

I am trying to salvage test data from an aborted Jenkins build. The documentation (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Aborting+a+build) appears to throw an interrupt and so I attempted to catch it with a custom handler:

`signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)`

Running my program through CMD and sending crtl-c stimulates the signal_handler function. However, when running this through Jenkins, the interrupt signal is not captured. Are there any plugins that alter Jenkins abort signal, or is there a way to handle it gracefully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I know this a bit late, but jenkins sends a `TERM` signal when aborting. Basically you just gotta register that signal

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)
```

Info obtained from: 
https://gist.github.com/datagrok/dfe9604cb907523f4a2f

where it says:

> ## Jenkins
>
> When a Jenkins job is cancelled, it sends `TERM` to the *process group* of
>   the process it spawns, and immediately disconnects, reporting "Finished:
>   ABORTED," regardless of the state of the job.
>
> This causes the spawned process and all its subprocesses (unless they
>   are spawned in new process groups) to receive `TERM`.
>
> This is the same effect as running the job in your terminal and pressing
>   CTRL+C, except in the latter situation `INT` is sent, not `TERM`.
>
> Since Jenkins disconnects immediately from the child process and reports
>   no further output:
>
> - it can misleadingly appear that signal handlers are not being
>     invoked. (Which [has mislead
>     many](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17116) to
>     think that Jenkins has `KILL`ed the process.)
> - it can misleadingly appear that spawned processes have completed or
>     exited, while they continue to run.